# Stub response for AWS S3 Ruby SDK

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-ruby

I'm looking for a way to test my code that relies on AWS S3. I found the [Advanced Client Stubbing tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/advanced-client-stubbing-in-the-aws-sdk-for-ruby-version-3/) but I was only able to find the correct way to stub `list_objects` from the `Aws::S3::Client` directly.

I don't want to refactor my code because I'm using the SDK with `Aws::S3::Resource` (a more OOP way):

```rb
s3_resource = Aws::S3::Resource.new(options)
objs = s3_resource.bucket(bucket_name).objects
```

The only way to successfully get the stubbed response I've been able to find so far is:

```rb
s3_client = Aws::S3::Client.new(stub_responses: true)
stubbed_objs = {
  contents: [
    { key: 'image.jpeg' },
    { key: 'test/image.jpeg' },
    { key: 'test/backup_2019-03-01T143129.sql.gz' },
    { key: 'test/backup_2019-04-01T143129.sql.gz' },
    { key: 'test/backup_2019-05-01T143129.sql.gz' },
    { key: 'test/image2.jpeg' },
    { key: 'backup_2019-06-01T143129.sql.gz' },
    { key: 'backup_2019-07-01T143129.sql.gz' },
    { key: 'backup_2019-08-01T143129.sql.gz' }
  ]
}
s3_client.stub_responses(:list_objects, stubbed_objs)
res = s3_client.list_objects({ bucket: "examplebucket" })

# Check the stubbed response
res.contents.map(&:key)
# => ["image.jpeg", "test/image.jpeg", "test/backup_2019-03-01T143129.sql.gz", "test/backup_2019-04-01T143129.sql.gz", "test/backup_2019-05-01T143129.sql.gz", "test/image2.jpeg", "backup_2019-06-01T143129.sql.gz", "backup_2019-07-01T143129.sql.gz", "backup_2019-08-01T143129.sql.gz"]
```

I've tried passing the `Aws::S3::Client` to the `Aws::S3::Resource` initializer, but I'm not getting the response objects from the stubs:

```rb
s3_client = Aws::S3::Client.new(stub_responses: true)

...

s3_resource = Aws::S3::Resource.new({ client: s3_client })
objs = s3_resource.bucket(bucket_name).objects
# => Returns 0 objects
```

I'm thinking `s3_resource.bucket(bucket_name).objects` makes multiple calls and that's why it's failing, or maybe the stubbed response format is different when using a `Aws::S3::Resource` vs direct `Aws::S3::Client` call.

Either way, any help with this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

make a stub_responses using list_objects_v2, not list_objects
it'll work

```rb
    s3_client = Aws::S3::Client.new(stub_responses: true)
    stubbed_objs = {
      contents: [
        { key: 'image.jpeg' },
        { key: 'test/image.jpeg' },
        { key: 'test/backup_2019-03-01T143129.sql.gz' },
        { key: 'test/backup_2019-04-01T143129.sql.gz' },
        { key: 'test/backup_2019-05-01T143129.sql.gz' },
        { key: 'test/image2.jpeg' },
        { key: 'backup_2019-06-01T143129.sql.gz' },
        { key: 'backup_2019-07-01T143129.sql.gz' },
        { key: 'backup_2019-08-01T143129.sql.gz' }
      ]
    }
    s3_client.stub_responses(:list_objects_v2, stubbed_objs)
```